# Recursive function exploration using thread pool, limiting Queue size

Tags: c++, multithreading, recursion, queue, threadpool

I have modified the library ctpl_stl.h for thread pool. According to my problem, I must use a recursive function which calls itself twice, so I get C1 and C2 from the first and second call respectively. Then before reaching the end of the function, C1 and C2 could be compared.

This is a tree exploration, C1 represents left-hand, and C2 right hand. I want to set a limited number of threads, basically depending on the capabilities of my machine. For this test, I am only creating two threads in the pool.

Every time I push a function while using the pool.push(function, ... arguments...), I enqueue this function (task) into a Queue which will be assigned to any available thread after these ones finish their job, so this Queue will be able to increase up to half of the leaves of the tree due to the left-right hand exploration.

While debugging my code, I discovered that at some point tasks 0 and 1, which are already assigned to threads 0 and 1 (not respectively because of the way they work), will be waiting for the results of task ie. 2 and 3, but this task won't be executed because they are waiting for any available threads. So it basically reaches a deadlock.

So I think I solved the deadlock by limiting the Queue size, then no task will be enqueuing if there are no available threads at the moment.

Then I modified part of the thread pool library to limit the Queue size with a simple conditional verifying its size always before enqueuing something, if this size is smaller than the threads created in the pool, then it means there are available threads to assign a new task.

It sounds pretty nice the idea, but it is not working, I am pretty sure it is reaching a deadlock somewhere. I do not know if my enqueuing limitation is working or not (probably not).

But definitely the library works since, after creating a number of threads equivalent to 50% of leaves of a tree, then everything works fine.

The problem is that the number of leaves is theoretically determined by 2^n, where n is the size of my sample (size of the input vector in code). so creating millions threads is not a practical choice.

All the modifications to the library are commented by //Modification by me

This is a project of a graduate course, any ideas what could be wrong? thank you in advance

main.cpp

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include "ctpl_stl.h"
#include <string>

ctpl::thread_pool pool(2);

int leaves = 0;
int nodes = 0;

std::vector<int> function(int id, std::vector<int>& A, std::vector<int>& B, int left, int right) {
    int tmp;
    if (A.size() == 0) return B;
    //left and right are only values to check while debugging which hand i am exploring, not relevant in the code

    std::vector<int> A1 = A;
    std::vector<int> A2 = A;
    std::vector<int> B1 = B;
    std::vector<int> B2 = B;
    std::vector<int> C1;
    std::vector<int> C2;

    bool tempo = pool.check();
    std::future<std::vector<int>> C1_tmp;

    //left hand exploring
    tmp = A1.back();
    A1.pop_back();
    B1.push_back(tmp + 1);
    //Inside the pool, if Queue.size() is smaller than Threads {ie. Pool(2)}
    //Then it means there is an available thread, so we add the function to the Queue to be run by this
    //available thread. If not, it C1_tmp will return a false and function for C1, will be
    //called by current thread.
    C1_tmp= pool.push(function, ref(A1), ref(B1),1,0);
    if (!C1_tmp.valid()) {
        C1 = function(id, A1, B1, 1, 0);
    }


    //righ hand exploring
    tmp = A2.back();
    A2.pop_back();
    B2.push_back(tmp + 1);
    C2 = function(id, A2, B2,0,1);
    //Get value from future so the running current thread could explore righ-hand
    //while any available thread explore left-hand
    if (C1_tmp.valid()) {
        C1 = C1_tmp.get();  
    }

    /*Join right Thread with left Thread*/

    //There will be some comparison between C1 and C2

    leaves++;
    return C1; /*or C2, does not matter yet*/
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A, B, C;
    int val = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        A.push_back(i);
    }

    clock_t begin = clock();
    int tempo = pool.n_idle();
    printf("Number of available threads: %i \n", tempo);
    C = function(0, A, B, 0, 0);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Number of leaves: %i \n", leaves);
    printf("Elapsed time = %.2lf \n", elapsed_secs);

    return 0;
}
```

ctpl_stl.h

```
/*********************************************************
*
*  Copyright (C) 2014 by Vitaliy Vitsentiy
*
*  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
*  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
*  You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
*  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
*  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
*  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
*  limitations under the License.
*
*********************************************************/


#ifndef __ctpl_stl_thread_pool_H__
#define __ctpl_stl_thread_pool_H__

#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>



// thread pool to run user's functors with signature
//      ret func(int id, other_params)
// where id is the index of the thread that runs the functor
// ret is some return type


namespace ctpl {

    namespace detail {
        template <typename T>
        class Queue {
        public:
            bool push(T const& value) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
                this->q.push(value);
                return true;
            }
            // deletes the retrieved element, do not use for non integral types
            bool pop(T& v) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
                if (this->q.empty())
                    return false;
                v = this->q.front();
                this->q.pop();
                return true;
            }
            bool empty() {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
                return this->q.empty();
            }
            int size() {    //modification by me
                return q.size();
            }

        private:
            std::queue<T> q;
            std::mutex mutex;
        };
    }

    class thread_pool {

    public:

        thread_pool() { this->init(); }
        thread_pool(int nThreads) { this->init(); this->resize(nThreads); }

        // the destructor waits for all the functions in the queue to be finished
        ~thread_pool() {
            this->stop(true);
        }
        //modification by me
        bool check() {  //Check if queue is smaller than pre-set threads
            std::size_t val = q.size();
            if (val < threads.size()) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        // get the number of running threads in the pool
        int size() { return static_cast<int>(this->threads.size()); }

        // number of idle threads
        int n_idle() { return this->nWaiting; }
        std::thread& get_thread(int i) { return *this->threads[i]; }

        // change the number of threads in the pool
        // should be called from one thread, otherwise be careful to not interleave, also with this->stop()
        // nThreads must be >= 0
        void resize(int nThreads) {
            if (!this->isStop && !this->isDone) {
                int oldNThreads = static_cast<int>(this->threads.size());
                if (oldNThreads <= nThreads) {  // if the number of threads is increased
                    this->threads.resize(nThreads);
                    this->flags.resize(nThreads);

                    for (int i = oldNThreads; i < nThreads; ++i) {
                        this->flags[i] = std::make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(false);
                        this->set_thread(i);
                    }
                }
                else {  // the number of threads is decreased
                    for (int i = oldNThreads - 1; i >= nThreads; --i) {
                        *this->flags[i] = true;  // this thread will finish
                        this->threads[i]->detach();
                    }
                    {
                        // stop the detached threads that were waiting
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
                        this->cv.notify_all();
                    }
                    this->threads.resize(nThreads);  // safe to delete because the threads are detached
                    this->flags.resize(nThreads);  // safe to delete because the threads have copies of shared_ptr of the flags, not originals
                }
            }
        }

        // empty the queue
        void clear_queue() {
            std::function<void(int id)>* _f;
            while (this->q.pop(_f))
                delete _f; // empty the queue
        }

        // pops a functional wrapper to the original function
        std::function<void(int)> pop() {
            std::function<void(int id)>* _f = nullptr;
            this->q.pop(_f);
            std::unique_ptr<std::function<void(int id)>> func(_f); // at return, delete the function even if an exception occurred
            std::function<void(int)> f;
            if (_f)
                f = *_f;
            return f;
        }

        // wait for all computing threads to finish and stop all threads
        // may be called asynchronously to not pause the calling thread while waiting
        // if isWait == true, all the functions in the queue are run, otherwise the queue is cleared without running the functions
        void stop(bool isWait = false) {
            if (!isWait) {
                if (this->isStop)
                    return;
                this->isStop = true;
                for (int i = 0, n = this->size(); i < n; ++i) {
                    *this->flags[i] = true;  // command the threads to stop
                }
                this->clear_queue();  // empty the queue
            }
            else {
                if (this->isDone || this->isStop)
                    return;
                this->isDone = true;  // give the waiting threads a command to finish
            }
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
                this->cv.notify_all();  // stop all waiting threads
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(this->threads.size()); ++i) {  // wait for the computing threads to finish
                if (this->threads[i]->joinable())
                    this->threads[i]->join();
            }
            // if there were no threads in the pool but some functors in the queue, the functors are not deleted by the threads
            // therefore delete them here
            this->clear_queue();
            this->threads.clear();
            this->flags.clear();
        }

        template<typename F, typename... Rest>
        auto push(F&& f, Rest&&... rest) ->std::future<decltype(f(0, rest...))> {
            //Modification by me--------------------RELEVANT CHANGE
            if (!check()) { //mine, function returns false value if Queue.size() < Number of threads
                std::promise<std::vector<int>> prom;
                prom.~promise();
                return prom.get_future();
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------
            auto pck = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(f(0, rest...))(int)>>(
                std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::placeholders::_1, std::forward<Rest>(rest)...)
                );



            auto _f = new std::function<void(int id)>([pck](int id) {
                (*pck)(id);
                });

            this->q.push(_f);
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
            this->cv.notify_one();


            return pck->get_future();
        }

        // run the user's function that excepts argument int - id of the running thread. returned value is templatized
        // operator returns std::future, where the user can get the result and rethrow the catched exceptins
        template<typename F>
        auto push(F&& f) ->std::future<decltype(f(0))> {
            auto pck = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(f(0))(int)>>(std::forward<F>(f));
            auto _f = new std::function<void(int id)>([pck](int id) {
                (*pck)(id);
                });
            this->q.push(_f);
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
            this->cv.notify_one();
            return pck->get_future();
        }


    private:

        // deleted
        thread_pool(const thread_pool&);// = delete;
        thread_pool(thread_pool&&);// = delete;
        thread_pool& operator=(const thread_pool&);// = delete;
        thread_pool& operator=(thread_pool&&);// = delete;

        void set_thread(int i) {
            std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<bool>> flag(this->flags[i]); // a copy of the shared ptr to the flag
            auto f = [this, i, flag/* a copy of the shared ptr to the flag */]() {
                std::atomic<bool>& _flag = *flag;
                std::function<void(int id)>* _f;
                bool isPop = this->q.pop(_f);
                while (true) {
                    while (isPop) {  // if there is anything in the queue
                        std::unique_ptr<std::function<void(int id)>> func(_f); // at return, delete the function even if an exception occurred
                        (*_f)(i);
                        if (_flag)
                            return;  // the thread is wanted to stop, return even if the queue is not empty yet
                        else
                            isPop = this->q.pop(_f);
                    }
                    // the queue is empty here, wait for the next command
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mutex);
                    ++this->nWaiting;
                    this->cv.wait(lock, [this, &_f, &isPop, &_flag]() { isPop = this->q.pop(_f); return isPop || this->isDone || _flag; });
                    --this->nWaiting;
                    if (!isPop)
                        return;  // if the queue is empty and this->isDone == true or *flag then return
                }
            };
            this->threads[i].reset(new std::thread(f)); // compiler may not support std::make_unique()
        }

        void init() { this->nWaiting = 0; this->isStop = false; this->isDone = false; }

        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> threads;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<bool>>> flags;
        detail::Queue<std::function<void(int id)>*> q;
        std::atomic<bool> isDone;
        std::atomic<bool> isStop;
        std::atomic<int> nWaiting;  // how many threads are waiting

        std::mutex mutex;
        std::condition_variable cv;

        //Modification by me
        int numThreads() {
            return threads.size();
        }
    };

}

#endif // __ctpl_stl_thread_pool_H__
```

Comment: `prom.~promise();` Don't do this. This makes the call of `prom.get_future()` on the next line Undefined Behavior since `prom` has been destroyed.  Manually calling the destructor like that is almost always an error.

Comment: Thank you for replying, this is the only way I could find so the function could return something, that matches the type, and that could give me a false when using C1_tmp.valid()